# Moving mysql datadir cause info: checking for tables which need an upgrade

Tags: mysql

So after moving the data directory to another partition, I get this error:

```
[info] checking for tables which need an upgrade, are corrupt or were not closed cleanly.
```

This is on Debian 7.5.

The steps I took to do this:

- service mysql stop
- nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf
- changed datadir=/data/mysql
- cp -pr /var/lib/mysql /data/
- service mysql start

When I did a mysqlcheck, all tables in mysql db say OK. What else am I missing to get rid of this error?

Comment: Occasionally the service command doesn't catch all running instances of a given application; it basically just runs a Sys V init script. Try stopping MySQL again, then look for any stragglers with 'ps -Af | grep mysql'. If you see one, kill it and then start with the service command.

Answer (score 1):

This is an [info] message and displays due to the steps taken by the Debian mysql startup script. It is not an error.